# How to configure Apache JMeter in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jmeter

I want to setup apache jmeter in eclipse.i downloaded source file and then add project into eclipse but then i get following error..i also downloaded binary files and i don't know where to add those files.but i didn't find any resources on the internet regarding this.

```
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access F:\Users\NaTzI\JavaEE\lib
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access F:\Users\NaTzI\JavaEE\lib\ext
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access F:\Users\NaTzI\JavaEE\lib\junit
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache.log cannot be resolved
    The import com.thoughtworks cannot be resolved
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    The method getLoggerForClass() from the type LoggingManager refers to the missing type Logger
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    ConversionException cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type
    Logger cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<init>(JMeter.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:216)
JMeter home directory was detected as: F:\Users\NaTzI\JavaEE
```

What should i do???

Comment: The question is old, but I thought to comment as this is still a problem. I faced same challenges when I started customizing JMeter and thought to utilize Eclipse to do the customization. In the section "2. Run JMeter using ANT target" of below link I have covered the ANT issue and other end to end configuration issues one may face.
[http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/](http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

Main class: org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver

Working directory: ${workspace_loc:apache-jmeter/bin}

Classpath: all jars in apache-jmeter/lib and apache-jmeter/lib/ext