# Debugging JMeter Java Request class single stepping in Eclipse

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to load test some java classes I developed with the Eclipse IDE. I have added a Java Request and added JMeter code as needed into the runtest method.

How can I start Jmeter and then have it single step into my classes using Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19332966/2003273

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add debug line to Java arguments of JMeter by i.e. running it in [command line non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as follows

On Windows

`set JVM_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`

on Linux/Unix/MacOX

`JVM_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 && export JVM_ARGS`

after that:

`jmeter -n -t {path_to_your_jmx_scipt} -l {path_to_jtl_results_file}`

In Eclipse

- navigate to Run | Debug (See Figure 2: Create new Remote Java Application configuration in Eclipse )
- Select Remote Java Application , on the left column. Click New , on the bottom of the same column
- In the Create configuration screen you'll be prompted to enter some values. Start with a meaningful name. Let it be JMeter or something like that
- For Project, select the Java project that contains the JMeter Java Sampler source code you want to debug. Leave Connection Type in default, i.e. Standard (Socket Attach) . For Host , enter localhost. If you want to debug a remote server, enter its hostname or IP address. For port, enter 8000 or the port you defined in your your `JVM_ARGS`

Comment: So it is not possible to display the GUI and when the Java class runs Eclipse does a breakpoint. Is this correct?

Comment: It is possible. JVM_ARGS are applicable to GUI mode as well. When the breakpoint will be hit you won't be abble to access the GUI however.

Comment: FYI: For Windows the environ command is works as above.

However for Mac OS X the environ setting command is: 

export JVM_ARGS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"

Also runs fine in GUI mode just cant make changes to GUI while single stepping the java code. Which makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the approach above in Eclipse but got an error: 'Launching JMeter encountered a problem": Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

Comment: Detailed Eclipse configuration instructions are available in the [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article under **Remote JMeter Debugging** section